# Efficient filtering of many options in QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, filter, pyqt5

Using PyQGIS, I am developing a QGIS plugin that includes a filter function. It should make handling easier for users (internal) who rarely use QGIS.

Now I have created a interface with the QT Designer that contains several checkboxes.

- Each checkbox contains criteria that can be used to filter.
  Every checkbox is set at the start.
- With uncheck the checkbox, a more precise selection is activated via a combo box. Let's assume every combo box has 3 different attributes.
- At the end, the filter should be started with the appropriate selection via the push button. The visualization looks like this:

[image]

The code gets pretty fast, pretty long, and cluttered.

```py
def Filter_starten():
    if checkbox1.isCheck():
        "take attributes"
    else:
        "take other attributes"
    
    if checkbox2.isCheck():
        "take attributes"
    else:
        "take other attributes"
    
    if checkbox1.isCheck() and checkbox2.isCheck():
        "take attributes"
    else:
        "take other attributes"
    
    if checkbox2.isCheck() and checkbox3.isCheck():
        "take attributes"
    else:
        "take other attributes"
```

And so on..

How can I efficiently program the multitude of possible options in the `Filter_starten()` function? How do I avoid a confusing number of if-clauses?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really a GIS question or could be instead asked in StackOverflow. However, you might be interested in reviewing the strategy pattern, which I've used in the [Load Them All plugin](https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall) to apply a number of filters (and all their possible combinations) on both vector and raster layers. Have a look at [this diagram](https://i1.wp.com/downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/geoblogs/plugin_LoadThemAll/imgs/Class_Diagram_1_4.png) and [at the code itself](https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall/blob/master/Filter.py).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could loop through the checkboxes, using the [`isChecked()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/Detailed/QgsDetailedItemData.html#qgis.gui.QgsDetailedItemData.isChecked) method to ascertain whether they are checked and if so, set all combobox items to checked. Then eventually, get all the checked items from the comboboxes and store them in a dictionary.

Something like:

```py
## make a dict using the comboboxes as keys and their various options as values
comboboxes = {combobox1:['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], 
              combobox2:['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], 
              combobox3:['option1', 'option2', 'option3']}

## initialise an empty dict
checked_items = {}

## loop through checkboxes
for i,cb in enumerate([checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3]):
  if cb.isChecked():
    ## if checkbox is checked, set all items in combobox to checked
    list(comboboxes.keys())[i].setCheckedItems(comboboxes[list(comboboxes.keys())[i]])

  ## set the checked items of each combobox against the combobox in the checked items dict
  checked_items[list(comboboxes.keys())[i]] = list(comboboxes.keys())[i].checkedItems()
    
## do something with the checked items
```

This way, however the comboboxes are configured will be captured when the button is clicked, and automatically checked based on the checkboxes.

I can't test this right now, but hopefully it gives you some ideas.

I am assuming you are using [QgsCheckableComboBox](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/gui/QgsCheckableComboBox.html) for the selections should the checkboxes be unchecked.